# Magento 2 Category url rewrite is not working

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, migration, magento2-migration-tool

After migration by using ubertheme, my category url is not working.
Its showing all category urls are like below
http://domain.com/catalog/category/view/s/trouvez-le-fauteuil-ou-canape-chesterfield-fait-pour-vous/id/51/

Can you pleas help me how can i change it to seo format?

I have tried reindexing via ssh and also enable seo url for category and product from Configuration/catalog/SEO tab.

I am using magento 2.1.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

**Download "Regenerate Url rewrites" extension from here :** https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

**Follow the below steps**

**MANUAL INSTALLATION**

1. Extract files from an archive
2. Create a `app/code/OlegKoval/RegenerateUrlRewrites` folder in magento root directory, and copy the extracted files from Step1 folder and upload it to directory `app/code/OlegKoval/RegenerateUrlRewrites`
3. Disable the cache under `System > Tools > Cache` Management
4. Enter the following at the command line

> php bin/magento module:enable OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**HOW TO USE IT**

To re-generate all Url rewrites of the categories/products in all stores (it support a multistores) run

> php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate

To regenerate all Url rewrites of the categories/products in the specific store view (e.g.: store view id is "2")

> php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate 2

Comment: use that but still my categories are redirecting to 404 error .

Comment: That worked for me on Magento 2.3.2 Community, also solved other issues with not being able to add items to Cart or Sign in.

Answer (score 1):

Followup of @chris

Incase you, like me, have gotten the task to save a shop which has migrated their store completely wrong here's a functioning script which takes a categoryId and attempt to recreate the category url_rewrite from the category request path to magento's internal mapping of category id.

You can use this in combination with `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` to walk through every category in your store

This is a function taken from a console command i made to walk the entire store ( https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html )

`$this->output` is just the `OutputInterface`
`$this->storeId` is the current store you which to use.

```
    public function handleRedirect($categoryId)
    {
        try {
// use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
            /** @var Category $category */
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
// use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator;
            $requestPath = $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category);

            $this->output->writeln('<info>Processing: ' . $category->getName() . '</info>');
            $this->output->writeln('<comment>' . $requestPath . '</comment>');

// use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory; 
            /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite $rewrite */
            $rewrite = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create();

            $rewrite->setStoreId($this->storeId);
            $rewrite->setRequestPath($requestPath);
            $rewrite->setEntityType('category');
            $rewrite->setEntityId($category->getId());
            $rewrite->setTargetPath('catalog/category/view/id/' . $category->getId());
            $rewrite->setRedirectType(0);
            $rewrite->setDescription('Category Regeneration');

// use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewrite
            $this->urlRewriteResource->save($rewrite);

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
            $this->output->writeln('<error>' . $e->getMessage() . '</error>');
        }
    }
```

This method is non-destructive as it does not duplicate existing urls and only helps fill out the void that some poor soul has created when migrating categories incorrectly :(

Before attempting it check you link, if it's somewhere along the lines of `catalog/category/view/id/<id>` you can manually create a url_rewrite in the backend ( select category and pick your category ) you can then create it and test it before running the script

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because there is no URL rewrite in Magento. Check your URL rewrites, if that category doesn't exist then create it. In Marketing > URL re-writes > Add URL re-write:

[image: Add new URL rewrite]

Flush cache, reindex the site and try again.